# How to limit the user to enter 4 digit pin in java

Tags: java

I want to take input of pin from the user and I want to limit the user to take 4 digit pin. I tried with [But when I enter 0001 it's not working it again ask to enter 4 digit pin then please solve it

```
void pin1()
{
    //int pin;
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        try
        {
                pin=obj.nextInt();
                if(pin<=9999 && pin>=1000)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Pin must be four digit");
                    pin1();
                }

            break;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            obj.next();
            System.out.println("Error use numbers not alphabets or characters");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is with 0001 or 0123 means when i write the 0 on left side it will not working

Comment: Take the input as a `string` and simply check its `length`

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the wrong type for a pin. As `int` values, `0001` and `1` are the same values, but the latter is an invalid pin, while the former is valid.

You should use a `String` to store the pin. This means you should call `nextLine` instead of `nextInt`:

```
String pin = obj.nextLine();
```

To check if this pin contains 4 digits, we can use the regex `\d{4}`.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}").matcher(pin);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("You have entered a 4-digit pin");
} else {
    System.out.println("You have not entered a 4-digit pin");
}
```

Alternatively, you can check with a for loop:

```
if (pin.length() != 4) {
    System.out.println("You have not entered a 4-digit pin");
} else {
    boolean allDigits = true;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(pin.charAt(i))) {
            allDigits = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (allDigits) {
        // pin is valid
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error use numbers not alphabets or characters"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
do { 
System.out.print("Please enter a 4 digit pin:"); 
input = reader.nextLine(); 
if(input.length()==4){
    //allow

}

}while( input.length()!=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is

```
`if(pin<=9999 && pin>=1000)`
```

allows numbers between 1000 and 9999 but 0001 or 0300 is still a valid 4 digit number

The code allows only `numeric` and does not allow `alpha numeric`
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Post7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\d+";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please input a valid 4 digit pin");
        while(true) {
            String ln = sc.nextLine();
            if(ln.length() == 4 && ln.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println("valid input "+ln);
                break;
            }else {
                System.out.println("please input a valid 4 digit pin");
            }
        }
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `0001` as integer which becomes `1` which does not satisfies the condition `pin>=1000`. One thing you can do is first check the length of the string and if it is not 4 then return an error. Then if it is correct trying to convert to an integer: if there is an error maybe the user did not inserted 4 digits.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    int pin;
    int attempt = 0;
    
    while(attempt < 3) {
        
        System.out.print("Enter PIN: ");
        pin = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        s.nextLine(); //spacing for 2nd and 3rd attempts
        
        if(pin >= 1000 && pin <= 9999) break;
        else System.out.println("Please try again."); 
        System.out.println("");
        attempt ++;
    }
    
    if(attempt < 3) System.out.println("You have successfully logged in!");
    else System.out.println("Your card has been locked.");
    
}
```